# "java.security.AccessControlException: access denied" while connecting google CCS

Tags: google-app-engine, xmpp, google-cloud-messaging, smack

I  have followed the tutorial at the link https://developer.android.com/google/gcm/ccs.html#implement.
I am using Smack 4.0.4.

I have created an endpoint for the method "connect" and deployed this class on google app engine.

However when I call "connect" from my android mobile client app, i get exception as shown below.

What does this exception mean?

Any helpful comment is appreciated!

```
WARNING: Cannot connect to CCS server.
java.security.AccessControlException: access denied ("java.lang.RuntimePermission" "modifyThreadGroup")
at java.security.AccessControlContext.checkPermission(AccessControlContext.java:372)
at java.security.AccessController.checkPermission(AccessController.java:559)
at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkPermission(SecurityManager.java:549)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerFactory$CustomSecurityManager.checkPermission(DevAppServerFactory.java:429)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerFactory$CustomSecurityManager.checkAccess(DevAppServerFactory.java:454)
at java.lang.ThreadGroup.checkAccess(ThreadGroup.java:315)
at java.lang.Thread.init(Thread.java:389)
at java.lang.Thread.init(Thread.java:349)
at java.lang.Thread.<init>(Thread.java:444)
at org.jivesoftware.smack.tcp.XMPPTCPConnection$PacketWriter$1.<init>(XMPPTCPConnection.java:1240)
at org.jivesoftware.smack.tcp.XMPPTCPConnection$PacketWriter.init(XMPPTCPConnection.java:1240)
at org.jivesoftware.smack.tcp.XMPPTCPConnection$PacketWriter.<init>(XMPPTCPConnection.java:1227)
at org.jivesoftware.smack.tcp.XMPPTCPConnection.initConnection(XMPPTCPConnection.java:484)
at org.jivesoftware.smack.tcp.XMPPTCPConnection.connectUsingConfiguration(XMPPTCPConnection.java:463)
at org.jivesoftware.smack.tcp.XMPPTCPConnection.connectInternal(XMPPTCPConnection.java:831)
at org.jivesoftware.smack.AbstractXMPPConnection.connect(AbstractXMPPConnection.java:298)
at com.example.mymodule.XMPPServer.SmackCcsClientEndpoint.connect(SmackCcsClientEndpoint.java:276)
at com.example.mymodule.XMPPServer.SmackCcsClientEndpoint.getInstance(SmackCcsClientEndpoint.java:73)
at com.example.mymodule.connectionServlet.CcsServlet.init(CcsServlet.java:24)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.initServlet(ServletHolder.java:440)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.getServlet(ServletHolder.java:339)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:487)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1166)
at com.google.appengine.api.socket.dev.DevSocketFilter.doFilter(DevSocketFilter.java:74)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.ResponseRewriterFilter.doFilter(ResponseRewriterFilter.java:127)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.HeaderVerificationFilter.doFilter(HeaderVerificationFilter.java:34)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
at com.google.appengine.api.blobstore.dev.ServeBlobFilter.doFilter(ServeBlobFilter.java:63)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
at com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.TransactionCleanupFilter.doFilter(TransactionCleanupFilter.java:43)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.StaticFileFilter.doFilter(StaticFileFilter.java:125)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerModulesFilter.doDirectRequest(DevAppServerModulesFilter.java:366)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerModulesFilter.doDirectModuleRequest(DevAppServerModulesFilter.java:349)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerModulesFilter.doFilter(DevAppServerModulesFilter.java:116)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:388)
at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:182)
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:765)
at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:418)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppEngineWebAppContext.handle(DevAppEngineWebAppContext.java:98)
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.JettyContainerService$ApiProxyHandler.handle(JettyContainerService.java:490)
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:326)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:542)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.content(HttpConnection.java:938)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:755)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:218)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:404)
at org.mortbay.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:409)
at org.mortbay.thread.QueuedThreadPool$PoolThread.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:582)
```

Comment: just to be sure, to use xmpp your project has to be whitelisted. Did you do that?

Comment: @ThMBc - I had done that two days back but I haven't received any confirmation yet. However the page also says -  

    "Update:

     Upstream Google Cloud Messaging and User Notifications are now     open to all developers!

    Please go to https://developer.android.com/google/gcm for more     information."                                                             So should it matter?

Comment: The implementation guide you are following is for a server side implementation. So the request for the connection is handled as a servers' request. https://developer.android.com/google/gcm/client.html#sample-send is the one for clients. This message gets handled by the google servers. The connection to your server is refused, since the 2nd part of the adventure needs to be whitelisted.

Comment: @ThMBc - So you mean after the request is granted it should work fine?Also do you have any idea, how long it takes to approve the request?

Comment: mine did take about a week. I think this is your problem but I can be mistaken. If you just implement the client side of your app only that should work now. but I suspect that if you want to run server side code you have to be whitelisted.

Comment: @ThMBc - Hey Is this the correct link to request to whitelist - https://services.google.com/fb/forms/gcm/  ? I had submitted almost two weeks back, but haven't got any reply from google yet. On submit I was hoping at least an acknowledgement mail from google stating that my request is sent and will be processed. I am not able to proceed at all. Do you know of any google support contact for this?

Comment: Did you manage to resolve this issue Shailesh? I'm also interested in doing what you are doing and I'm research the net for tutorials - sadly there is not a lot of them being written up on GAE, Smack and Android.

Comment: @Simon Sadly I have not been able it yet and been getting much time to look into it. I will update the moment I find something. Please let me know too if you could fix it. That would be great help! thanks in advance. :)

Comment: In the meantime, I have looked at this tutorial - http://www.appsrox.com/android/tutorials/instachat/ but it is not the same as using XMPP. It is sending the messages from your android device on endpoints, and then using GAE to connect to GCM to send the message to the other device. It is not the most efficient way to do it but it works and there are no delays in msg delivery. I have tested it and the messages goes from one phone to another phone instantly. I don't know if it would scale well though...